# WMS with basic authentication

Tags: leaflet, gis, basic-authentication, wms

I have several layers protected with basic authentication in Geoserver (WMS). Authentication works fine with QGIS, but when I try to authenticate with Leaflet, nothing loads.

I've researched but haven't found much information.
I was reading the leaflet documentation and couldn't find a solution.